# How can you add two random variables (with different values) together in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

This is my code as shown below. My first set is Fibonacci numbers, the second is Lucas Numbers

```
var f1 = 1;
var f2 = 1;
var f3 = 2;
var f4 = 3;
var f5 = 5;
var f6 = 8;
var f7 = 13;
var f8 = 21;
var f9 = 34;
var f10 = 55;
var f11 = 89;
var f12 = 144;
var l1 = 1;
var l2 = 3;
var l3 = 4;
var l4 = 7;
var l5 = 11;
var l6 = 18;
var l7 = 29;
var l8 = 47;
var l9 = 76;
var l10 = 123;
var l11 = 199;
var l12 = 322;
var num;
var num2;
```

I have it so that if num = 1, then you add fibonacci, if num = 2, then you add the lucas numbers.

```
function question(){
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if(num = 1){
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Find the two numbers in the Fibonacci Series which when added together make" + _______ // What goes here?
}
if(num = 2){
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Find the two numbers in the Lucas Series which when added together make" + _______ // What goes here?
}
}
```

In the blank area, what goes there? I want to put the sum of 2 random variables (as shown above).

Comment: Put your values into an array and use random numbers as indexes to the array

Comment: What is the purpose of variable "num2", you're not using it after assigning random number to it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, create two arrays holding the numbers as follows :

```
let fibNums = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144];
let lucasNums = [1,3,4,7,11,18,29,47,76,123,199,322];
```

As the next step create a function which can return the sum of two random numbers based on the array

```
function generateSum(arr, x, y){
 console.log(arr[x], arr[y]); // the selected values from the array 
 return arr[x] + arr[y];   
}
```

Now just call the function with the array name and by generating random index

```
generateSum(arrayName , Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayName.length), Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayName.length))
```

Based on your use case

```
if(num = 1){
generateSum(fibNums , Math.floor(Math.random()*fibNums.length), Math.floor(Math.random()*fibNums.length))
}
if(num = 2){
generateSum(lucasNums , Math.floor(Math.random()*lucasNums.length), Math.floor(Math.random()*lucasNums.length))
}
```